# Django Page Does Not Save

Tags: django

I'm working on a simple app that act similar to wikipedia using the tutorial "create a wiki in 20 minutes " from showmedo .

The app works by you create a page e.g dog if it doesn't exist then you add all the info about dogs and it display the dog and details of the dog.[image]

When I try to edit the same page . the page doesn't get updated on the main page either does it get updated on my admin page.
[image]

I think the problem is with my save_page function and edit_page function.
So when I create a page , it works
but when I try to retrieve the page and save it . It doesn't save .

The only method that works is editing the page by admin.

I think the problem is here

```
def save_page(request, page_name):
    content = request.POST.get('content', 'this is the default')
    try:
        page = Page.objects.get(pk=page_name)
        page.content = content
```

This is the website 
http://tafe.pythonanywhere.com/wikicamp/Dogs/

My views.py

```
from wiki.models import Page
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response 
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.template import RequestContext
def view_page(request,page_name):
    try:
        page = Page.objects.get(pk=page_name)
    except Page.DoesNotExist:
        return render_to_response("create.html",{"page_name":page_name})
    content = page.content
    return render_to_response("view.html",{"page_name":page_name , "content":content}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
def edit_page(request,page_name):
    try:
        page = Page.objects.get(pk=page_name)
        content = page.content
    except Page.DoesNotExist:
        content = ""
    return render_to_response("edit.html",{"page_name":page_name, "content":content}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
def save_page(request, page_name):
     content = request.POST.get('content', 'this is the default')
     try:
         page = Page.objects.get(pk=page_name)
         page.content = content
     except Page.DoesNotExist:
         page = Page(name=page_name, content=content)
         page.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect("/wikicamp/" + page_name + "/")
```

My create.html

```
 <html>
    <head>
        <title>{{page.name}} - Create </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>{{page_name}} </h1>
        This page does not exist. <a href="{% url wiki:edit page_name %}">Create?     </a>
 </body>
 </html>
```

My edit.html

```
     <html>
    <head>
        <title>{{page_name - Editing</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Editing {{page_name}} </h1>
        <form method = "post" action="{% url wiki:save page_name %}"> {% csrf_token %}
                <textarea name="content" rows="20" cols="60">     {{content}}
      </textarea><br/>      
            <input type="submit" value="Save Page"/>
            </form>
        </body>
      </html>
```

My view.html

```
<html>
    <head>
    <title>{{page_name}}</title>
        </head>
    <body>
        <h1>{{page_name}} </h1>
        {{content}}
        <hr/>
        <a href="{% url wiki:edit page_name %}">Edit this page ?</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: http://tafe.pythonanywhere.com/wikicamp/Dogs/ Try it out . :]

Comment: I'm bit confused on your codes. In your edit.html your saving it to save url instead in edit url

Comment: How can you save your edited content if you dont have save method in edit_page view and you don't have also request.POST for content

Comment: Look at your tab title, `{{ page_name }}` has not been rendered!

Comment: Okay . I'm gonna go fix

Comment: @donkeyboy72 try msc answer

Comment: Thank you veryone for helping me . I will not forget this mistake again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 try:
     page = Page.objects.get(pk=page_name)
     page.content = content
 except Page.DoesNotExist:
     page = Page(name=page_name, content=content)
     page.save()
```

Two problems I see here. First, you are trying to retrieve the page by the `page_name` as the primary key, when you should be searching on the `name` attribute, and secondly after you have fetched the page successfully and updated its content, you forget to save it.

Since this is a common pattern, there is a shortcut in django [`get_or_create`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.get_or_create), it works like this:

```
 page, created = Page.objects.get_or_create(name=page_name)
 if created:
    # new page was created
 else:
    # existing page was retrieved
```

In your scenario, you just want to fetch and update the contents in either scenario. So we don't need to use the `created` variable:

```
 page, created = Page.objects.get_or_create(name=page_name)
 page.content = content
 page.save()
```

Comment: Thank you . I will use this shortcuts in my further projects

Answer (score 1):

You're not saving the page in save_page, only when it doesn't exist. Try something like:

```
def save_page(request, page_name):
     content = request.POST.get('content', 'this is the default')
     try:
         page = Page.objects.get(pk=page_name)
         page.content = content
         page.save()
     except Page.DoesNotExist:
         page = Page(name=page_name, content=content)
         page.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect("/wikicamp/" + page_name + "/")
```

This is a quick ugly fix, I recommend looking into [forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/) and [class based views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/class-based-views/).

Comment: @msc Thank you very much . I'll look more closer in details next time

Comment: This won't work because you are checking the `pk` value against `page_name`, when you should be checking `name`.

Comment: @Burhan Khalid I get you . I should be getting the name of the model page .Page.objects.get(name=page_name)

Answer (score 1):

Two things I noticed with this:

```
 try:
     page = Page.objects.get(pk=page_name)
     page.content = content
 except Page.DoesNotExist:
     page = Page(name=page_name, content=content)
     page.save()
```

1) in the `try` block you are querying by `pk` and in the `except` you are setting the `name`.

2) you are not saving in the `try` block.

try this:

```
 try:
     page = Page.objects.get(name=page_name)
 except Page.DoesNotExist:
     page = Page(name=page_name)
 page.content = content
 page.save()
```

Answer (score 1):

you forgot to put save()

```
def save_page(request, page_name):
    content = request.POST.get('content', 'this is the default')
    try:
       page = Page.objects.get(pk=page_name)
       page.content = content
       page.save()
    except Page.DoesNotExist:
       page = Page(name=page_name, content=content)
       page.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect("/wikicamp/" + page_name + "/")
```